# Black hole accretion disks and quasars

Tags: black-holes, accretion-disk, quasars

Are 'accretion disk of a black hole'  and 'quasar' synonymous? If not, what's the difference?

Comment: What part of the definition in the wikipedia article confuses you? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasar

Comment: So quasars are basically the most energetic part of accretion disks, right?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/137837/, and http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/219911/

Answer (score -1):

No they both are different in there properties.I mean they are part of one  complete process with different properties..

..As [Quasar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasar) and [Accretion_disk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accretion_disk) states...

**Accretion Disk**

1. is a structure disk formed by **material** in orbit around central body(*star*).
2. got gravity causes material in the disk to spiral inward towards the central body.
3. is compressed by forces to raise the temperature of the material causing the emission of electromagnetic radiation.
4. has frequency range of that radiation depends on the central object's mass.

   Which means radiation for :

   1. Young stars and Protostars  : Infrared
   2. Neutron stars and Black holes : X-ray

   part of the spectrum.

*On other hand,*

**Quasar**

1. is **radio sources** are the most energetic object
2. they posses high [redshift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redshift) sources of electromagnetic energy.
3. radiate

   1. Radio waves
   2. Visible light
4. have luminosity 100 times greater than that of the Milky Way.
5. **are normally caused by collisions of galaxies, with the galaxies' central black holes merging to form either a supermassive black hole or a binary black hole system.**

**Summary :**

> *Accretion Disk* is a disk of **materials** around *star*.
>
> *Quasar* is **radio sources** formed when two galaxies collides centering single or binary black hole

Comment: The emissions from a quasar are from the *accretion disk* that surrounds a black hole, so I think your delineation here is a little strict/wrong.

Comment: ok let me correct myself in answer..

Comment: The last sentence of the introduction to the Wikipedia article you link states very clearly, *The energy emitted by a quasar derives from mass falling onto the accretion disc around the black hole.* This appears to contradict your entire post. You're also introducing a *non sequitur* with the formation of a quasar, ignoring *what* it is.

Comment: that's why stated they are part of a complete process with defferent properties

Comment: So does every black hole have a quasar?

Comment: no..galaxies(centered blackhole) collides to form quasar... basically we can say it is powered by black hole..as termed there is [scientific consensus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_consensus) that quasar is region surrounding by central supermassive black hole.